# From Delay Spread to Coherence Bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth, delay, coherence

The phase difference of two sinusoids is given as:

|  TX --(r)--->RX <------- (Reflection)|

d: whole path from sender to reflecting object

$ \Delta \theta = 2 \pi \cdot \frac{(2d - r)-r}{c} f + \pi $

The coherence bandwidth is given by: $ W_c := \frac{1}{(T_d)}$

$ W_c $ is $ f_1 - f_0 $, so basically I should somehow calculate that from the phase difference formula? But I'm missing the beginning.

Comment: whatever the unintroduced $d, r$ and $c$ are, and what a constant (i.e. not time-dependent) phase between two sinusoids has to do with bandwidth. We're missing 90% of information here! What's $f_1$, what is $f_0$? You have to realize that nobody but you knows the notation you use!

Comment: Also, you have questions where you've received answers, but haven't accepted one, although your comments seem to indicate sufficiency for acceptance. Please do that!

Comment: I added the needed information. f_1 and f_2 is the frequency offset.